# How to read from a file and save to 4 different variables (C#)?

Tags: c#, sql, streamreader, system.io.file

Im trying to create a settings file with the information for my SQL database, but the issue I am currently having is I cant seem to read each line and save it to a different variable.

```
 private void readFile()
    { 
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Settings.txt", true))

            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                CurrentLine = sr.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
```

Im not sure how I would set it up so that I can write each different line to my 4 variables.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A different approach would be to not reinvent the wheel and use [ConfigurationManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is designed for application settings and connection strings.

Comment: The app.config file is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array instead which you can access via index:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Settings.txt");
string firstLine = lines[0];
// and so on, keep in mind that it could have less lines
```

A `StreamReader` approach with your four variables is much more cumbersome:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Settings.txt", true))
{ 
    string line;
    int currentLineNumber = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        switch (++currentLineNumber)
        {
            case 1: first = line; break;
            case 2: second = line; break;
            case 3: third = line; break;
            case 4: fourth = line; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I have needed to store settings in a file, I created a class to hold the information, e.g.

```
public class Settings{
   public string ConnectionString {get;set;}
   public string DatabaseName {get;set;}
   public DateTime Started {get;set;}
}
```

Saving settings:

```
var settings = new Settings(){
   ConnectionString = "blah blah blah",
   DatabaseName = "blah blah blah",
   Started = DateTime.Now,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:/Settings.txt", json);
```

Loading settings:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/Settings.txt");
var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

I found this reliable, flexible and stable.
It also means you don't have to worry about converting between (e.g.) DateTime and String. You also don't need to worry about the order of the setting values.

(This uses the Json.NET package.)